# xterm not loading config with -name

Tags: xterm

I have a xresources file to customise xterm and running `xrdb -merge` it loads in fine. Starting a new xterm with `xterm`, I can confirm it has been loaded in OK.

However when I start a new xterm with `xterm -name foobar` it looses my config and goes back to the defaults.

This is an issue because I am using multixterm which in the background is starting xterms with the -names argument.

How can I maintain my xterm config between different -names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **class** `XTerm` instead of the name `xterm` in your resources. This will match all xterms, whatever their name. For example, do not use

```
xterm*VT100.geometry:+250+2
```

but do use

```
XTerm*VT100.geometry:+250+2
```